# Dont modify program, print some values as output - unusual (?) homework

Tags: c++

I have a problem with, to me, unusual homework:

> Dont modify the main function but change the program that it prints as
>   output:
>
> - Monday
> - is the first day
> - of the week

And heres the given code:

```
int main()
{
  cout << "is the first day\n";
}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Remember that you don't have to run a program from a shell or Window environment, you can start a program from another program.

Comment: I suggest you go back to the person who set this work and ask them to clarify what they meant. The only way I can see to do this would be to do something completely evil like `#define` cout to mean something else.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes, I know but thats not it. The command is to modyify the program, except main

Comment: This is encouraging terrible coding style.

Comment: Folks, why downvote? Its a homework my teacher gave me and told to do it  "exaclty as he said" - its not my fault that is senseless, for me its too...

Comment: There are solutions that are not that atrocious. It raises some possibly interesting questions about programinitialization and termination or about namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another atrocious idea, just for the fun of it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define main real_main
int main()
{
    cout << "is the first day\n";
}
#undef main

int main()
{
    cout << "Monday\n";
    int res = real_main();
    cout << "of the week\n";
    return res;
}
```

Another version which does not rely on preprocessor foo would be to use global static object construction and destruction. This is safe, since apparently the standard guarantees that `std::cout` (and friends) is initialized and destroyed before/after all user code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Homework
{
    Homework()
    {
        cout << "Monday\n";
    }
    ~Homework()
    {
        cout << "of the week\n";
    }
} hw;

int main()
{
    cout << "is the first day\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What he's undoubtedly interested in your demonstrating is the fact that a global object (defined in the same translation unit) will be constructed before main is entered, and destroyed after main exits.

Be aware that when such a global object is being constructed, `std::cout` may not exist yet (and when it's being destroyed, `std::cout` may no longer exist), so any printing you do just about has to be via C functions like `printf`.

Comment: That (the part about cout not being initialized) is not true. Read about `class std::ios_bas::Init` and how it comes into play through the `<iostream>` header.

Comment: @JoergB: It depends on the compiler and the version of C++ it supports. If the compiler supports C++11, it should work. C++03 has a non-normative footnote expressing the intent that it should work, but to my knowledge nobody's ever found normative language to support that as a real requirement (and there are real compilers for which it doesn't work). See C++03, §27.3/2 and footnote 265 if you want more details.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a poor homework question. I can see no way to print other outputs without modifying the main method - unless you created another main method to override this?! The code provide is wrong as well - it should return 0 as main is expected to return an integer.

Comment: In C++, if `main` doesn't return anything then the compiler adds an implicit `return 0` at the end.

Comment: @Konrad: I know it too but my teacher told me to do it "exaclty as he said" :/

Comment: sorry - have more been brought up in c and java so forgot about the implicit return

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        cout << "Monday\nis the first day\nof the week\n";
        exit(0);
    }
} X;

int main()
{
    cout << "is the first day\n";
}
```

**Update**
Ok, you may use name 'cout' in main func like some object not from iostream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    public:
        void operator <<( const std::string & s )
        {
            std::cout << "Monday\n" << s << "of the week";
        }
} cout;

int main()
{
    cout << "is the first day\n";
}
```

Comment: tricky but Im afraid thats not it

Comment: Why not? It exactly does what was required...

Comment: @yak What's not it? There is no correct answer to your question. Do you have an answer in mind?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of ways you can do this.

- You can replace the meaning of `cout`.
- You can make things happen before and after `main` is called.

Redefining `cout`:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyCout {};

void operator<<(MyCout& myCout, const char* message) {
    std::cout << "Monday\n";
    std::cout << message;
    std::cout << "of the week\n";
}

MyCout cout;

int main()
{
    cout << "is the first day\n";
}
```

To making things happen before and after main, you can create a static object. Their constructor is called before main, and the destructor afterwards:

```
#include <iostream>

class PrintExtras {
public:
    PrintExtras() {
        std::cout << "Monday\n";
    }
    ~PrintExtras() {
        std::cout << "of the week\n";
    }
};

PrintExtras printExtras;

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout << "is the first day\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of things that happen before entry into main or after exit from main.

- Early in a program you typically have initialization, at the end its counterpart.
- What is the C++ idiom for those things?
- How can you make those happen outside the body of main()?
- What do you know about objects defined at namespace scope?

It really depends on where you are with your course, if you know about these things.

**Alternative**: The object used in main is only `std::cout` if you bring that name into the global namespace. Objects in namespaces other than ::std can also bear that name.